# Passing default answers to apt-get package install questions?

Tags: configuration, scripting, apt

I'm trying to write a configuration script for new servers, and one of the first steps is to install a series of required packages, such as MySQL, phpMyAdmin, etc. using `apt-get install` However, when dpkg tries to configure them it asks you for a few options, such as MySQL root password, phpMyAdmin passwords, what server to use, etc.

Since I will likely be passing this script on to co-workers who are unlikely to read the prompts, and my desire to simply start it and walk away, **I'd like to know how to pass in a series of "default" answers/values for it to use.** This might include usernames/passwords/other dynamic values passed on command line.

--

I realize that having passwords in a script is a security issue, but I'm willing to ignore it, particularly in the more general sense of installing packages that an answer to this would imply.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use debconf's configuration preseeding.

Do a test install to get the values that you want:

```
root@test1:~# apt-get install mysql-server
```

..and set the root password when prompted during the install.

Then you can check what the debconf settings look like for what you just installed (you may need to install `debconf-utils`):

```
root@test1:~# debconf-get-selections | grep mysql-server
mysql-server-5.5        mysql-server/root_password_again        password
mysql-server-5.5        mysql-server/root_password      password
mysql-server-5.5        mysql-server/error_setting_password     error
mysql-server-5.5        mysql-server-5.5/postrm_remove_databases        boolean false
mysql-server-5.5        mysql-server-5.5/start_on_boot  boolean true
mysql-server-5.5        mysql-server-5.5/nis_warning    note
mysql-server-5.5        mysql-server-5.5/really_downgrade       boolean false
mysql-server-5.5        mysql-server/password_mismatch  error
mysql-server-5.5        mysql-server/no_upgrade_when_using_ndb  error
```

There's some noise there, but the important part is the password settings.

Then, for a fresh install, you can avoid the prompts completely by setting the password beforehand:

```
root@test2:~# echo "mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password_again password Som3Passw0rd" | debconf-set-selections
root@test2:~# echo "mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password password Som3Passw0rd" | debconf-set-selections
root@test2:~# apt-get install mysql-server
```

No prompts at all during that install.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install debconf-utils` as necessary.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I'll give it a try shortly.

Comment: Aside from a known error with phpMyAdmin not accepting a pre-seeded MySQL root password, this works perfectly!

Comment: just wondering, is there a way to get possible debconf settings from the package system without installing the packages?

Answer (score 23):

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get -q -y install _packages_
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for what's reading $DEBIAN_FRONTEND?

Comment: This has been a part of Debian for so long that I think only [Ian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_Murdock) could really tell you when it was added.

Comment: @Andrew It's read by [debconf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man7/debconf.7.html#contenttoc4), which is what actually deals with the questions.

Comment: @mgorven Ahh, I've not gone much deeper than dpkg before.

Comment: AFAIK, this solution only allows you skip the prompt and accept the default to all answers. If you want to set a non-default answer you have to use another solution, such as the `debconf-set-selections` method.

Comment: Note for Docker environments. This solution only works when called in a single line. For example, `RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && apt-get -q -y install libglib2.0-dev`. Trying to call as 2 separate RUN commands will still show interactive prompts.

Answer (score 4):

The debconf package contains [`debconf-show`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/debconf/debconf-show.1.en.html):

```
debconf-show package
```